# How to parse the json data coming from server side using jQuery in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

I m creating a Blood Donation app using Nodejs and express.js.Below is my server site code.

```
app.post('/SearchDoner', function(request, response) {
  var store;
  console.log('here');
  console.log(request.body);
  console.log(request.body.bg);
  console.log(request.body.c);
  var bg = request.body.bg;
  var city = request.body.c;
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log('select txtFullname,gender,email,address,bgp,mno from information   where   bgp =' +"'"+ bg + "'" + "and city =" + "'" + city +"';");
  connection.query('select txtFullname,gender,email,address,bgp,mno from information  where  bgp =' +"'"+ bg + "'" + "and city =" + "'" + city +"';", function(err, rows) {
     response.json(rows);
     console.log(rows);
     });
  });
```

And below is the Client side ajax call :

```
 function fetchDoner()
  { 
 var BloodGroup = $("#dpBloodGroup").children("option").filter(":selected").val();
 var City = $("#dpCity").children("option").filter(":selected").val();
 console.log(BloodGroup);
 console.log(City);
     $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/SearchDoner",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:({bg:BloodGroup,c:City}),    
        crossDomain: "true",      
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result,function(index,obj){
          console.log(obj.txtFullname);
              $("#DonerInfo_5").append("<tr><td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  + obj.txtFullname + "</span></td>" + "<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.address + "</span></td>" + "<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.gender + "</span></td>" +"<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.mno + "</span></td>" +"<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.email + "</span></td></tr>");
      }); 
  var newUrl = 'http://localhost/Blood%20Donation%20Site_1/donerinfo.html';
  document.location.href = newUrl;
         },error: function (obj, txtStatus, error) {
       }
    });
  }
```

The problem is that the json data which is coming from the server site(from app.post() method) is not get parsed at donerinfo.html page.

Comment: can u do a console.log(result) and post here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle query result for stable application. If you have error, your js cannot parse simple err string. However, If you handle it, you can give proper response to user and prevent parsing incorrect string. In below code, Response error is checked. In JS, for only successfull result responded json iterated;

```
.....
connection.query('select txtFullname,gender,email,address,bgp,mno from information  where  bgp =' +"'"+ bg + "'" + "and city =" + "'" + city +"';", function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({type: false, data: err});
        } else {
            res.json({type: true, data: JSON.stringify(rows)});
        }
     });
  });
  ....
```

And in your js;

```
  ......
  $.ajax({
        url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/SearchDoner",
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:({bg:BloodGroup,c:City}),    
        crossDomain: "true",      
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.type == false) {
                alert("Error occured:" + result.data);
                return false;
            }
            $.each(JSON.parse(result.data),function(index,obj){
          console.log(obj.txtFullname);
              $("#DonerInfo_5").append("<tr><td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  + obj.txtFullname + "</span></td>" + "<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.address + "</span></td>" + "<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.gender + "</span></td>" +"<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.mno + "</span></td>" +"<td style='color:;background: #FDC68F;''><span>"  +  obj.email + "</span></td></tr>");
      });

......
```

Comment: i m not getting any error even after updating the code ..

Comment: Ok then you have no result returned. If there is no result, it will not enter iterating part. Could you please post the result of `console.log(rows)` on controller part? I just need to know if any rows fetched

Comment: @ Huseyin there is result of console.log(rows) :                    [
  {
    "txtFullname": "ram",
    "gender": "M",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "address": "A-219,Sec-19,Noida",
    "bgp": "AB+",
    "mno": "7696457545"
  },
  {
    "txtFullname": "Harinder",
    "gender": "F",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "address": "abc nagar",
    "bgp": "AB+",
    "mno": "9643043471"
  }
]

Comment: On js side, what is the output of `console.log(result)` in success callback?

Comment: nothing comes there....

Comment: Is your ajax call success? Could you please look at firebug console network tab response section. Is it empty or returns something?

Comment: may be it is working because that "document.location.href" is working and it is under the success portion ....

Comment: It may enter in success callback but, you need to check `result` in success callback. Check console.log(result);

Comment: on doing console.log(result) i m getting : {type: true, data: Array[2]}

Comment: Could you please try `JSON.stringify(rows)` ? I have also updated my question. Your array object must be json.

Comment: yes...now i m getting :                                          {type: true, data: "[{"txtFullname":"ram","gender":"M","email":"ram@gmail.com","bgp":"AB+"},{"txtFullname":"Harinder Kaur","gender":"F","email":"abc@gmail.com","bgp":"AB+"}]"}

Comment: Your problem fixed now?

Comment: But sir on using  "console.log(obj.txtFullname)" in $.each() method,i m still getting undefined.

Comment: You are iterating `result.data` right?

Comment: yes..i m iterating through result.data

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(resut.data)`;

Comment: Use this `$.each(JSON.parse(result.data), function(index, obj)`

Comment: By doing this i m getting :                                       "[{"txtFullname":"ram","gender":"M","email":"ram@gmail.com","bgp":"AB+","mno":"7696457545"},{"txtFullname":"Harinder ","gender":"F","email":"abc@gmail.com","bgp":"AB+","mno":"9643043471"}]"

Comment: Ok use this `$.each(JSON.parse(result.data), function(index, obj)` as I updated in my answer also

Comment: thank u sir..problem is solved...